# Not able to access GCP bucket even when SA has storageAdmin on that bucket level

Tags: google-cloud-storage

My service account has storage.admin role on particular bucket but still not able to access the bucket.
That service account does not have any other role though.
What could be the reason.?

getting error : storage.bucket.access permission is required.
Thanks

Comment: Details are required. Not being able to access can mean many things. Read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then update your question.

Comment: Hi John

getting error saying storage.bucket.list permission is required

Comment: Which IAM Roles are assigned to your identity? The [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) lists the Cloud Storage IAM Roles. Search the page for IAM Roles that include the permission `storage.bucket.list`, such as `roles/storage.admin`. Note: It is important that you provide details on what you are doing that generated the error. The reason is that you might need another permission and by being clear upfront, you will save time trying to figure out the next issue. For example, you need to list buckets, what will you do next with a bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki for other's sake:

As for @John Hanley said:

> Which IAM Roles are assigned to your identity? The [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) lists the Cloud Storage IAM Roles. Search the page for IAM Roles that include the permission storage.bucket.list, such as roles/storage.admin. Note: It is important that you provide details on what you are doing that generated the error. The reason is that you might need another permission and by being clear upfront, you will save time trying to figure out the next issue. For example, you need to list buckets, what will you do next with a bucket?

Additional reference:

- [IAM permissions for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions)